# Two "$(document).ready(function()" on the same page cause problems, how to handle?

Tags: jquery

i have a web page with a fix header included by a simple `include("header.php")`, in this header i have a jquery function that begins with: `$(document).ready(function() {`. One of my pages, need to have another jquery function on the body, if i put two times in the same page the function $(document).ready(function() { one of them stop to work. How can i handle this?, as you can see i cant put the scripts on the same position because one have to be always on the header and the other one appear only in some pages. Thanks!

Comment: Are the 2 nested? If they are not having 2 or more document.ready on the same page shouldn't be a problem. Please show how your markup looks like and explain what problems do you encounter (`stop working` is not a good problem description).

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML and the code? If you create a JSFiddle, we can change your code to working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery handles multiple event handlers, so there is nothing that keeps you from having multiple `ready` event handlers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VysPB/

There has to be something inside the event handlers that keeps them from working in the same page.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a comment?

Comment: So that you could write the same answer? ;) (joke, This is a good one.)

Comment: @roXon, from what you can see I already wrote the same comment in the question before this answer.

Comment: Argh! Next time before logging-in I promise I'll sleep a few hours more!